# SageMaker Batch Transform Input filter

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run inference using SageMaker Batch Transform.
My data input for prediction has two columns:

```
ID, Text
```

Basically, doing some prediction based on test data.
However, I do not need ID field going to the prediction.

I tried using input_filter="[1:]", and the job keeps failing.
Below is my setup:

```
transformer.transform(
    batch_input_path, 
    content_type="text/csv", 
    split_type="Line", 
    logs=True,   
    input_filter="$[1:]",
)
```

Any suggestion on how I can achieve this without manually dropping the ID columns?

Also, what does "$[1:]" represent in input_filter? is it filtering the rows or columns?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$[1:]`: indicates that we are excluding column 0 (the 'ID') before processing the inferences and keeping everything from column 1 to the last column (all the features)

Kindly see [this example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/93163a8a75529984a7f8b0093d75e11f3f6cfb6a/sagemaker_batch_transform/batch_transform_associate_predictions_with_input/Batch%20Transform%20-%20breast%20cancer%20prediction%20with%20high%20level%20SDK.ipynb) that showcases how to make use of input/output/joining filter feature of Batch Transform.